# How to install oracle sqlplus 12.2 on Mac OSX Sierra (and get past library problems)

Tags: oracle, macos, sqlplus, macos-sierra

**tl;dr**

sqlplus 12.2 on Mac OSX Sierra gives me dynamic library problems. How to get past it?

> dyld: Symbol not found: _ons_recvthread_config_node   Referenced from:
>   /Users/myaccount/instantclient_12_2/libons.dylib   Expected in: flat
>   namespace
>
> Segmentation fault: 11

**Pardon the Yet-Another-Question**

This question has been asked a few times. Apparently Oracle substantially changed 'library setups'  for sqlplus/instantclient 12.2.  (So instructions for 12.1 no longer apply)

Plus  techniques (export LD_LIBRARY_PATH) that worked on older versions of MacOSX no longer work.

So i've gone ahead and created a new question to disentangle the old from the new.

**Library Setup Instructions**

I've followed the instructions here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html#ic_osx_inst

..and paid carefully ran "both versions" of step 3

> 3. Add links to $HOME/lib or /usr/local/lib to enable applications to find the libraries. For example, OCI based applications could do:
>
>    mkdir ~/lib   ln -s ~/instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.dylib ~/lib/   ln
>      -s ~/instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.dylib.12.1 ~/lib/
>
> Alternatively, copy the required libraries. For example, to use OCI
>   applications:
>
> mkdir ~/lib   cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
>   ~/lib/   cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libclntshcore.dylib.12.1
>   ~/lib/   cp /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libons.dylib ~/lib/   cp
>   /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libnnz12.dylib ~/lib/   cp
>   /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/libociei.dylib ~/lib/   ln -s
>   ~/lib/libclntsh.dylib.12.1 ~/lib/libclntsh.dylib

thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a possible alternative.  Have you considered sqlcl, instead of SQL*Plus?  It's a Java program, so no library incompatibility issues, and it is considerably more feature-rich.

Comment: Excellent! "SQLCL" meets my needs and thus works around the problem. Thanks!